# AngularJS Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] with SVG

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

Newbie to Angular (1.6.1). Trying to do something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat='thing in list'>
<svg class="icon" aria-hidden="true"><use xlink:href="#icon-{{ thing.icon }}"></use></svg>
</li>
```

Basically I want to determine which SVG sprite to use based on the value of "thing.icon".

But Angular gives me "Error: [$interpolate:noconcat]", which it says is a security protection against XSS: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/noconcat

Any thoughts on how to avoid this, and/or better approaches? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, too, which was fixed by adding an `ng-href` with with the content of `xlink:href` while leaving the `xlink:href` empty. Via mathewbyrne's workaround on this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7697

So try:

```
<li ng-repeat='thing in list'>
<svg class="icon" aria-hidden="true"><use ng-href="#icon-{{ thing.icon }}" xlink:href=""></use></svg>
</li>
```